# Alternatives à la finale « -é » tonique dans « Chanté-je juste ? »

Tags: conjugaison, questions, interrogative

Le [Grevisse](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Le_Bon_Usage) note pour la première personne du singulier (794b dans l'édition 2008) :

> ***-é*** au lieu de *-e* quand le pronom *je* est placé après le verbe, le `[ə]` final étant devenu `[ɛ]` tonique […] Toutes ces tournures appartiennent exclusivement à la langue littéraire.

Les exemples donnés incluent : « me trompé-je ? », « … commencé-je en cherchant mes mots », « du moins n'éprouvé-je pas », « eussé-je autant aimé », « Ô puissé-je », « Dussé-je ».

Il se trouve que j'utilise régulièrement cette construction pour les interrogatives au présent de l'indicatif (voir le premier exemple). Mon problème est : à part la très moche transformation en « est-ce que je » :

> Me trompé-je ? → Est-ce que je me trompe ?

Y a-t-il d'autres moyens de reformuler afin d'éviter ce qui pourrait apparaître aujourd'hui comme une marque de pédanterie ?

Comment: Dans un contexte informel, la forme *Je me trompe ?* est sans doute acceptable.

Comment: Comme tout le monde l'a déjà fait remarquer: cette tournure est indubitablement pédante (et son esthétisme fait débat). Il est important de noter que malgré l'usage de la lettre 'é', la forme se lit **'è'**. Par ex. "disé-je" se lit en fait comme "disè-je" (joies du français). Cette différence me parait assez importante du point de vue de l'euphonie.

Comment: Attention, pas d’accent pour le *Grevisse*.

Comment: Le "é" tonique remplaçant un "e", je crois que "disé-je" est de toutes façons incorrect. A mon avis c'est "Que dis-je?" Par contre, le passé ("Que disais-je") se prononce effectivement "è".

Comment: "Mange-je?" est mon préféré car il implique qu'on le prononce la bouche pleine si la réponse est "oui".

Comment: @Joubarc: parfaitement raison... Je me suis en effet lancé dans un barbarisme... La même remarque devrait s'appliquer pour un exemple valide, comme "mangé-je", "trompé-je" etc.

Comment: Effectivement, le <é> se prononce [ɛ] dans cette construction. On peut d'ailleurs écrire « me trompè-je ? » depuis [la réforme de 1990.](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectifications_orthographiques_du_français_en_1990)

Comment: On peut dire « Me trompe-je » `/tʁɔ̃pʒ/` pour embêter les académiciens.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Je pense que la « très moche » transformation « Est-ce que je me trompe ? » est la seule vraiment correcte. Par contre, de plus en plus de gens l’abrègent en « Je me trompe ? ». De la même manière, d'ailleurs que de plus en plus de gens diront « Tu crois ? » au lieu de « Crois-tu ? ». Je gage que ces gens-là trouveront « Crois-tu ? » aussi pédant que « Me trompé-je ? ».

Answer (score 2):

Et *Ai-je chanté juste ?*

Cela n'a pas tout à fait la même signification, mais ça peut se dire aussi bien à l'écrit qu'à l'oral, dans les mêmes circonstances.

Quelqu'un qui voudrait dire « est-ce que je chante juste, en général ? » (sorte de présent permanent), dira n'importe quoi, mais pas ça ; il dira probablement : *Est-ce que je chante juste ?*

Comment: Dans les deux cas, tu utilises les tournures qu'il cherche à éviter, donc cela vaut-t-il bien la peine de déformer le sens pour ce faire ?

Answer (score 1):

En réponse à votre interrogation, il y a certainement d'autres moyens utilisés par la littérature, qui sans diminuer l'incise d'un discours, le réorganise ; par exemple :

- transformer le présent interrogatif en un verbe à l'infinitif :

  ~ faire répondre à la question à la première personne,
  ~ laisser la   réponse en attente pour intensifier l'attention sur les motivation de cette dernière.

> - se tromper sur ce sujet ? je le fais [parfois|toujours]/je ne le fais [pas|jamais]  ...
> - se tromper sur ce sujet ? cela est [im]possible, en effet dans telles circonstances, il m'arrive de [ne pas] ...

*Ajout*

Cela fonctionne aussi avec les autres verbes cités, mais lorsque le verbe n'est pas le premier mot passer par le substantif :

> - Ô pouvoir ! Partageras-tu ta puissance pour que j'obtienne ...
> - Ô pouvoir ! Tu me manques tant pour y arriver !

En revanche, lorsqu'il n'est pas en incise, le présent sonne mal, car l'ici et maintenant n'est plus et l'on fait référence à quelque chose de passé :

> - ... ai-je commencé en cherchant mes mots.