# Est-ce que je peux écrire : « Téléphone je à la police ? »

Tags: grammaire, conjugaison, questions, interrogative

La phrase initiale est « Je téléphone au médecin », si je veux poser la question en inversant le sujet, est-ce que « Téléphone je au médecin ? » est une forme correcte ? Quelles sont les autres possibilités ?

Comment: La réponse se trouve dans cette question: http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/120/alternatives-a-la-finale-e-tonique-dans-chante-je-juste :-)

Comment: je voir savoir seul si la phrase va bien, je devoirs faire la phrase interrogative avec les trois formes  :La forme inversée,La forme longue et La forme simple.

Comment: Il manque un trait d’union :)

Comment: telephone-je à la police? :)

Comment: ou alors, plus simplement: "J'appelle la police?"

Answer (score 14, accepted):

La forme grammaticalement correcte et la plus soutenue est « téléphoné-je à la police ». De manière générale, lorsque l'on inverse le verbe et le sujet et que le verbe est à la première personne singulier de l'indicatif présent, le verbe prend la terminaison `é` au lieu de `e`. Pour les verbes du deuxième groupe et les verbes irréguliers, il n'y a pas de telle exception, [sauf *pouvoir*](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/1249/je-peux-puis-je-si-je-puis-dire).

> J'aime. Aimé-je ?
>   Tu aimes. Aimes-tu ?
>   Je téléphone. Téléphoné-je ?
>   Je veux. Veux-je ?
>   Je peux. Puis-je ?

L'inflection se fait aussi bien dans les phrases interrogatives que dans les phrases affirmatives, du moment que le verbe est immédiatement suivi du mot *je*.

> Aussi n'aimé-je pas la danse où je me sens défaillant. ([Roger Quilliot, *Mémoires*, Odile Jacob, 1999](http://books.google.fr/books?id=hNROBbxLO2UC&pg=PA156&dq=%22aim%C3%A9+je%22))

À l'oral, on n'utilise que très rarement la forme de question consistant à inverser le sujet. Il est beaucoup plus courant d'employer la locution *est-ce que* (« Est-ce que je téléphone à la police ? ») ou de marquer la question uniquement par le ton interrogatif (« Je téléphone à la police ? »). La forme inversée sonne d'autant plus inhabituelle ici que les questions à la première personne au présent sont rares et que le verbe *téléphoner* est relativement récent.

Donc, dans un exercice scolaire, la forme correcte est *téléphoné-je*, mais la forme à utiliser en situation réelle est *est-ce que je téléphone*, ou *je téléphone ?* dans un contexte familier.

Answer (score 4):

Cette formulation (correcte) appartient à la langue littéraire :

> Téléphoné-je à la police ?

En langage courant, on dira plutôt :

> Est-ce que je téléphone à la police ?

Selon le contexte on peut se poser la question de la nécessité :

> Dois-je téléphoner à la police ?

Ou encore la question de savoir si on a à faire au bon interlocuteur :

> Suis-je bien en communication avec la police ?

Answer (score 0):

Non, « téléphone-je à la police » n'existe pas. Je ne suis pas sûr de ce qu'est la forme inversée, la forme longue et la forme simple. La seule interrogative qui puisse exister pour cette affirmation est :

> Est-ce que je téléphone à la police ?

ou

> Suis-je en train de téléphoner à la police ?

Téléphoner est une action qui prend du temps.

Comment: Eh si… Il ne demande pas forcément s'il est en train de téléphoner, il pourrait demander s'il doit téléphoner, par exemple.

Comment: @LeVieuxGildas: Je ne vois pas le rapport. *Téléphoné-je* peut être utilisé dans les deux cas. Dans le doute on ne change pas, surtout si ça rend la réponse fausse.

Comment: @Kareen : Ce n'est pas la question, il n'y a pas de trait d'union dans la question. S'il parle de la forme tout entière, avec *-je*, alors je pense que ma correction est bonne, et s'il veut répondre à l'énoncé très exact, au caractère près, de la question, alors il n'y répond pas.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez : Je ne suis pas sûr de comment comprendre la première citation (comme la deuxième, sous une autre forme, ou avec l'autre sens, i.e. *est-ce que je téléphone, plus tard ?*) (Et je n'y avais pas pensé la première fois, je te l'accorde.) Peut-être que mon commentaire s'avance trop sur la raison de son erreur, mais je continue de penser qu'il a voulu dire « *téléphoné-je* n'existe pas », à tort.

Answer (score 0):

"téléphoné-je", comme "aimé-je", ou "parlé-je".

Comment: Peux-tu préciser et sourcer ?

Answer (score 0):

Bon à savoir, dans le language courant placer un point d'interrogation à la fin d'une phrase indicative suffit pour la transformer en question. Il est donc parfaitement acceptable d'écrire :
"Je téléphone à la police ?"

La forme "Téléphoné-je à la police" est la plus correcte du point de vu strictement grammatical, mais elle est très peu utilisée en réalité et ne sonne pas bien dans les oreilles d'un français.

Comment: Je pense qu'on dirait plutôt "Téléphonerais-je à la police?"

Comment: "téléphonerais-je à la police" est une forme acceptable, mais pas au présent. Il s'agit d'un interrogation sur le futur