# La tournure « puissé-je » est-elle juste?

Tags: subjonctif, inversion

J’ai appris à utiliser l’inversion sujet-verbe de la première personne du singulier il y a un an et demi, mais j’ai rencontré quelques exemples bizarres. Celui qui m’a toujours confondue est écrit ci-dessus. On m’a dit qu’il s’agit du subjonctif, mais je n'ai pu créer qu’une phrase aujourd’hui qui me semble toujours bizarre:

> C’est la seule chose que puissé-je faire.

Grammaticalement, tout me semble juste: l’inversion après un pronom relatif et l’utilisation du subjonctif après « la seule », mais elle me semble un peu dégoutante à l’oreille. Alors, elle est juste?

Comment: Dégoutante ou déroutante ?

Answer (score 7):

La forme attendue est:

> C’est la seule chose **que je puisse** faire.

On peut aussi utiliser l'indicatif, plus factuel :

> C’est la seule chose **que je puis** faire. (littéraire)

ou le plus courant :

> C’est la seule chose **que je peux** faire.

La forme littéraire *puissé-je* existe bien, mais l'inversion n'est pas possible dans la phrase proposée car n'entrant dans aucun de ses [cas d'usage](https://books.openedition.org/pum/10265?lang=fr) (interrogative, exclamative, incise, etc.).

Elle aurait été possible dans :

> **Puissé**<sup>1</sup>**-je** seulement faire cette chose !

mais ce n'est plus employé aujourd'hui sauf quand un effet de style est souhaité. Des formes équivalentes de même sens rencontrées en français moderne sont :

> Que j'**aimerais pouvoir** faire cette chose !

> Ah, si je **pouvais** faire cette chose !

Voir aussi: [Alternatives à la finale « -é » tonique dans « Chanté-je juste ? »](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/120)

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Ce *é* étant prononcé /ɛ/ et pas /e/, les rectifications de la réforme orthographique de 1990 permettent de le remplacer par un *è* pour rendre l'orthographe plus conforme à la phonétique (puissè-je).</sub>